# Configuring user profiles with forms authentication

Tags: 2007, forms-authentication, user-profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Integrating SharePoint user profiles with forms authentication](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/integrating-sharepoint-user-profiles-with-forms-authentication)

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise. I have deployed a publishing portal. It is using a custom forms authentication solution, which is described in the following URL. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net + SharePoint Server 2007 SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975135.aspx

My question is how do I implement a user profile function if I use such a membership provider? By user profile function I mean: a logged in user could edit/view his/her profile (from the welcome menu at the top --> My settings)? Any sample is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt i already answer that in my answer the last time you asked almost the same question? [Integrating SharePoint user profiles with forms authentication](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1232/integrating-sharepoint-user-profiles-with-forms-authentication)

Anders

Comment: @Anders: If you find a question that's a dupe, please flag it and I'll close it. Thanks :-)